# How to refresh Oracle TNS service name in ODBC DSN DataSource?

Tags: oracle, odbc, amazon-rds

I changed Service_Name in ..\network\admin\TNSNAMES.ORA  file

Now when I open ODBC 64 bit DataSource > User DSN > MyOracleDSN > Configure = > I still find old Service_Name in the drop-down for TNS Service Name field.

Is it possible to refresh the Service_Name list in the drop-down to reflect the change ?

How ?

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7lu.png)

Comment: What, _exactly_ did you change in your tnsnames file?   If it was the (SERVICE_NAME = somename) parameter, then that is not what the odbc driver sees.

Comment: Where from ODBC driver sees TNS Service Name field  then if it is not from tnsnames.ora ? Yes I changed in (SERVICE_NAME = somename) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical tnsnames.ora entry

```
PDB01 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vbol83-02)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb01.localdomain)
    )
  )
```

The "service name" that the odbc adapter (just like any other client program) is the very first line:

```
PDB01 =
```

The odbc driver, just like any other oracle client program (sqlplus, etc) simply makes a call to the tns stack and says 'connect me to "some name"'.  The tns stack then looks for an entry for "some name" in the tnsnames.ora. In this example, "some name" is PDB01.  Finding it, then then uses the rest of the information (beginning with " (DESCRIPTION =") and constructs a request that is passed on to the os network layer.